# How to use enum member with same outer class name

Tags: java, enums

This is my class

```
public class RubiksCube{

    public enum Moves{

       FRONT,BACK,RIGHT,LEFT,UP,DOWN

    }
}
```

can I call the enum member like this  RubiksCube.FRONT

Comment: Of course not, since they are of type Moves, not of type RubiksCube

Comment: That would work: RubiksCube.Moves.FRONT

Comment: then how can I make it possible without using public static final int, by only grouping with enum

Comment: @D.Lawrence I know that will work but I want to call the member like without using the move's type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, unless you define a constant within `RubiksCube` that would refer to that `Moves` instance

```
class RubiksCube {

  public static final Moves FRONT = Moves.FRONT;

  ...

}
```

which doesn't sound like a great idea. Note that you can access it via `RubiksCube.Moves.FRONT` since your enum is public.

Comment: I think this will waste my time to rewrite it's as a constant

Comment: it's the only option if you don't "like" accessing it via `RubiksCube.Moves.FRONT` or redefining the enum `Moves` as a top-level class (it would allow you to do `Moves.FRONT`)

Comment: you can also do `import static <your-package>.RubiksCube.Moves.FRONT` which simplifies the access to it, and kinda hides the location where it comes from (unless you check the imports, of course)...

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot, you have use it with outer class like,

```
public class RubiksCube{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( RubiksCube.Moves.BACK );
    }

    public enum Moves{
       FRONT,BACK,RIGHT,LEFT,UP,DOWN
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

`FRONT` is member of `Moves`. That's why `RubiksCube.FRONT` will result in a compilation error.

Comment: You should at least try to provide some information that is not yet in the comments

Answer (score 0):

You can call like,

```
RubiksCube.Moves.FRONT
```

The reason is because the Moves enum would get compiled finally like,

```
public final class com.xyz.RubiksCube$Moves extends java.lang.Enum<com.xyz.RubiksCube$Moves> {
  public static final com.xyz.RubiksCube$Moves FRONT;

  public static final com.xyz.RubiksCube$Moves BACK;

  public static final com.xyz.RubiksCube$Moves RIGHT;

  public static final com.xyz.RubiksCube$Moves LEFT;

  public static final com.xyz.RubiksCube$Moves UP;

  public static final com.xyz.RubiksCube$Moves DOWN;

  private static final com.xyz.RubiksCube$Moves[] $VALUES;

  public static com.xyz.RubiksCube$Moves[] values();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #1                  // Field $VALUES:[Lcom/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves;
       3: invokevirtual #2                  // Method "[Lcom/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves;".clone:()Ljava/lang/Object;
       6: checkcast     #3                  // class "[Lcom/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves;"
       9: areturn

  public static com.xyz.RubiksCube$Moves valueOf(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #4                  // class com/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves
       2: aload_0
       3: invokestatic  #5                  // Method java/lang/Enum.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Enum;
       6: checkcast     #4                  // class com/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves
       9: areturn

  private com.xyz.RubiksCube$Moves();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: iload_2
       3: invokespecial #6                  // Method java/lang/Enum."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
       6: return

  static {};
  Code:
        0: new           #4                  // class com/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves
        3: dup
        4: ldc           #7                  // String FRONT
        6: iconst_0
        7: invokespecial #8                  // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
        10: putstatic     #9                  // Field FRONT:Lcom/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves;
        13: new           #4                  // class com/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves
        16: dup
        17: ldc           #10                 // String BACK
        19: iconst_1
        20: invokespecial #8                  // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
        23: putstatic     #11                 // Field BACK:Lcom/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves;
        26: new           #4                  // class com/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves
        29: dup
        30: ldc           #12                 // String RIGHT
        32: iconst_2
        33: invokespecial #8                  // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
        36: putstatic     #13                 // Field RIGHT:Lcom/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves;
        39: new           #4                  // class com/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves
        42: dup
        43: ldc           #14                 // String LEFT
        45: iconst_3
        46: invokespecial #8                  // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
        49: putstatic     #15                 // Field LEFT:Lcom/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves;
        52: new           #4                  // class com/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves
        55: dup
        56: ldc           #16                 // String UP
        58: iconst_4
        59: invokespecial #8                  // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
        62: putstatic     #17                 // Field UP:Lcom/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves;
        65: new           #4                  // class com/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves
        68: dup
        69: ldc           #18                 // String DOWN
        71: iconst_5
        72: invokespecial #8                  // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
        75: putstatic     #19                 // Field DOWN:Lcom/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves;
        78: bipush        6
        80: anewarray     #4                  // class com/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves
        83: dup
        84: iconst_0
        85: getstatic     #9                  // Field FRONT:Lcom/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves;
        88: aastore
        89: dup
        90: iconst_1
        91: getstatic     #11                 // Field BACK:Lcom/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves;
        94: aastore
        95: dup
        96: iconst_2
        97: getstatic     #13                 // Field RIGHT:Lcom/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves;
        100: aastore
        101: dup
        102: iconst_3
        103: getstatic     #15                 // Field LEFT:Lcom/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves;
        106: aastore
        107: dup
        108: iconst_4
        109: getstatic     #17                 // Field UP:Lcom/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves;
        112: aastore
        113: dup
        114: iconst_5
        115: getstatic     #19                 // Field DOWN:Lcom/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves;
        118: aastore
        119: putstatic     #1                  // Field $VALUES:[Lcom/xyz/RubiksCube$Moves;
        122: return
}
```

You can see how the enum gets compiled into class internally via,

```
javap -p -c RubiksCube\$Moves.class
```

Comment: you inserted a ton of disassembled code which might confuse the OP even further :)